# How to use a Runtime variable in grep command in Unix

Tags: unix

I have a Time.sh file which has the code to store the StartTime and EndTime, entered by the user in runtime. The code in Time.sh fie is

```
read -p "Enter Start Time : " StartTime
read -p "Enter End Time : " EndTime
echo "Start and End Time are:" $StartTime, $EndTime
```

The following is the code I used to get the StartTime and EndTime in Runtime.

```
$ chmod +x Time.sh
$ ./Time.sh
```

Now I have to use this values in the two variables and print the data in the file "Test.log". The data in Test.log file is as follows,

```
May 10 01:07:05 server1 user:err|error IIB[78658909]: error text
May 10 01:07:06 server1 user:notice superstp[78653958]: infotext notice text
May 10 01:07:07 server1 user:info syslog: infotext
May 10 01:07:08 server1 user:err|error IIB[78658909]: error text
May 10 01:07:09 server1 user:warn|warning IBM Java[78650709]: warning text
May 10 01:07:10 server1 user:info syslog: infotext
May 10 01:07:11 server1 user:err|error IIB[78658909]: error text
May 10 01:07:12 server1 user:warn|warning IBM Java[78650709]: warning text
May 10 01:07:13 server1 user:notice superstp[78653958]: infotext notice text
May 10 01:07:14 server1 user:info syslog: infotext
May 10 01:07:15 server1 user:warn|warning IBM Java[78650709]: warning text
```

I have used the following code,

```
grep < "$EndTime" Test.log
```

But it is not working. Can anyone help to use both the variables and get the data within the StartTime and EndTime. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried `grep "$EndTime" < Test.log` ?

Comment: Thank You Michael. But Still It delivers me all the data, Not just the data below the $EndTime. Can you help me to use both $StartTime and $EndTime? Is there any operator for "Between" or "Range"?

Comment: Do you need from $StartTime to $EndTime? Is your input sorted by time?

Comment: Ya I need the data from $StartTime to $EndTime.And Yes my input is sorted by time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should help:

```
BEGIN { Found = 0; EndFound = 0;}
{
    if($0 ~ Start)
    {
        Found = 1;
    }
    if($0 ~ End)
    {
        EndFound = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        if(EndFound == 1)
        {
            Found = 0;
        }
    }
    if(Found)
    {
        print $0;
    }
}
```

It should be run as `awk -v Start="01:07:06" -v End="01:07:10" -f program data_file`, where `program` contains the code above and `"01:07:06"` and `"01:07:10"` start and end times respectively.

This is an example only. Please change fit it for your exact requirements.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.Your query gives me the desired result. But one problem is that the result includes the StartTime but does not include the EndTime. It displays the result from `"01:07:06"` to `01:07:09`. How can I include `"01:07:10"` also?

Comment: I've modified the code above. It should print now end time, too. I could not test, though. Please try.

Comment: Thank you. Now EndTime is also included and its working fine.

Comment: I am also trying to make this process simpler. So I am using a grep command to get the same resultset.i.e, the data from `"01:07:05"` to`"01:07:10"`. I have used `$  grep "May 10 01:07:[0-1][5-9,0]" Test.log` and also `$ grep "May 10 01:07:([0][5-9]|1[0])" Test.log`. The problem is I am getting the data from `"01:07:05"` to`"01:07:10"` and also `"01:07:15"`. Any idea how can I eliminate  `"01:07:15"` data?

Comment: No, I do not know how to do what you need with grep. Do not forget, that my solution works for any time range while grep-only must be tweaked for any change of times.